# What does this ampersand mean in C?

Tags: c, syntax

I am looking at the c code:

```
 if((VAR_ON&3) > 1)
```

I am not sure what kind of variable VAR_ON is, my guess is it is a pointer, but what does the &3 at the end do to it? I apologize if this is a duplicate question, I just could not find any question regarding the ampersand AFTER a variable.

Comment: I apologize, I was unaware there were referred to as bitwise operators and I did not know to look for that. Is there any other particular reason for the down votes?

Comment: A better question would be:  What does && mean in C++?

Comment: Not knowing this indicates that you're a rank amateur in C and in programming in general.  As such you have to expect to take a few lumps when you ask a "dumb" question like that.  (Hint: Find yourself a good C reference to look up this sort of thing.)

Comment: @Jim That question would surely be duplicate, and that is not the question I am asking. I understand what && is, but that has a different meaning than &.

Comment: If 3 was a variable, like int three = 3; then would if((VAR_ON &three) > 1) be ambiguous?

Comment: @HotLicks What makes this a "dumb" question? Isn't this website for learning? I understand the question has already been asked, I just could not find any of these questions. How else would I go about learning this if I did not know they were to referred to as bitwise operators? Even with a reference book, without knowing what is called, where do I look in the book.

Comment: I put "dumb" in quotes for a reason -- the question *appears* "dumb" to those who have a modicum of C comprehension.  But note that any halfway decent reference would have a table of operators where you could look up `&` to see what it means.  Your failure to do such a simple reference does not make you look good.  Learning to use references is a critical part of your education.

Comment: I guess I did not think of the possability of the operators table. Thank you for direction in looking at reference books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As used in the question code, the ampersand '&' is a bitwise 'and' operation.

Example (assuming that VAR_ON = '21'):

```
VAR_ON  21(Decimal)    00010101(Binary)
       & 3(Decimal)  & 00000011(Binary)
       ------------  ------------------
         1(Decimal)    00000001(Binary)
```

Hence if VAR_ON is '21', the expression (VAR_ON&3) will evaluate to '1'. The 'if' condition would be false:

```
if((VAR_ON&3) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

& in that context will perform a bit wise AND operation.

So whatever VAR_ON is will be ANDed with 3 so that only the last 2 bits of the variable will be used in the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bitwise AND. That's not an ampersand "after a variable". That's a bitwise binary operator working on two operands: VAR_ON and 3.