# operators = and != in the same time

Tags: c

Recently i saw a code that prints number in binary system.
I dont understand line : `bit = (dec & 0x8000) != 0;`
Is there's anyone that can explan this to me?

```
int dec,n ;
short bit;


    printf("Insert number: ");
    scanf("%d", &dec);

    if (dec == 9999)  printf(" Out of range!"); 


    for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
        bit = (dec & 0x8000) != 0;
        printf("%d", bit);
        if (i % 4 == 0) printf(" ");
        dec <<= 1;
    }
    printf("\n");



return 0;
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this ampersand mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370797/what-does-this-ampersand-mean-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
bit = (dec & 0x8000) != 0 ;
```

is equivalent to:

```
if ( (dec & 0x8000) != 0 ) bit = 1;
else                       bit = 0;
```

but it is an *one-liner* for the `if-else` statement

`&` is the *bitwise and* operator which compares the binary record from `dec` and `0x8000` and returns the *1's* where there are both in `dec` and `0x8000`

little example: `11&5` returns `1` because `11 = 0b1011` and `5 = 0b101` and comparing (from right to left) we have only the last `1` in both numbers...

`0x8000` is hexadecimal for `32768`

hope this will help

Answer (score 3):

Assign to the variable `bit` a value of `1` if the result of evaluating `(dec & 0x8000)` is not equal to `0`; and a value of `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

the value of `(dec & 0x8000) != 0` is evaluated first as true or false(1 or 0) and then `bit` is assigned the value.

Answer (score 1):

This line takes the number you inserted from console and applies logical AND. For example, if you enter 1024 ( 0100 0000 0000 binary ), then you have 0100 0000 0000 & 1000 0000 0000 0000 ( which is 0x8000, every number is replaced with binary tetrad ). In this case result is 0 which isn't != 0 and then value of variable bit is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` operator is bitwise-and.  It is being used to mask off all bits from `dec` except bit `0x8000`.  The `!=` operator is a comparison operator.  It tests for two values being unequal.  If they are unequal, the result is 1.  Otherwise the result is 0.  So if bit `0x8000` of `dec` is non-zero, i.e. 1, then `bit` will be 1.  Otherwise it will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

It tests if the single bit set in the constant `0x8000` is set in `dec` or not. `&` is the *bitwise and* operator.

The result of `(dec & 0x8000) != 0` (which is either 0 or 1) is assigned to `bit`.

Personally I prefer `bit = !!(dec & 0x8000)`.